# How to avoid the 40 character maximum, when reading a filename from a Weblogic server?

Tags: groovy, weblogic, oracle-service-bus

I am trying to read the name of some files from a weblogic server.

```
dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
  println file.getName()
}
```

However the base filename must be too long, since it's cutted of when i print the file.getName(). Looking at the deployed jar, I have the file

> OnlineOfflineSomethingknowledgement-2.DDD

The result of the print however is

> OnlineOfflineSomethingknowledgement-2.D

It's like 40 characters is the maximum length of the filename.

Looking at the SB-console, and look at the list of files. The 40 character maximum is also present in the web view. Hovering the mouse over the filename though, will show the full name of the file.

Is there a way to get the full file name from the code?

Answer (score 0):

not clear of the environment of your script execution.

normally, there is no such limitation.

try to print the class of your `dir` and `file` variables and probably this will give you an answer.

Comment: The file is stored as the short filename. The long and correct filename is only accessable through the SBConsole. printing dir and file does not provide anything.

Comment: what is `dir`? how you create/get it? can you provide the result of `println( dir.getClass() )`

Comment: `String path = "some/path/to/destination"`
`def dir = new File(path)`